# Object allocations and their release

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller

What i understood about object allocations and its release in objective is ..this..
if suppose i allocated one object with alloc init then i need to release it after its last reference .
Like this way....

```
 MyViewController *myView=[MyViewController alloc ]init];
 [self.view presentModalViewController myView animated:YES];
  [myView release];
```

However if suppose i need    NSMutableArray . 
     and i set its as

```
  @property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *myArr;
```

and need this array through out my viewcontroller means for instance say ....  view has uitableview and its data source is this array (myArr).

And app is having its local copy of data storage through Sqlite3 .

so i m adding object to this array using select statemnt of sqlite 3 .

And as i need this data each time viewappears so i allocated this myArr in viewDidAppear 
as...

```
myArr=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and i need to add value to each cell of uitableview in cellForRowAtIndexPath () method .

Means its las refernce is in cellForRowAtIndexPath()

So my question is that where should i release this allocated object of myArr

thnx in advnce

Kind Regards 
Pagggyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proper place would be

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Comment: However this methd invoked once only if i am not wrong  i am allocating every time view appear

Comment: If you are only hiding and showing a view you could try doing it in `viewDidDisappear:`, just make sure you do not try to access it while the view is not visible